# Where should I post photos to get Facebook id and to be able to like them from iOS application

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Here is my task. I have some images/photos, you can view them in my application also you should be able to like/unlike them and see how many other people have already like. I use iOS SDK for logging in with Facebook credentials.

To like some object or get it likes number you should have some facebookID. So my question is where should I post my images to get that ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found two ways of solution my task.

First one is to use iOS Facebook SDK. Then you have to post your photos and video somewhere to get IDs. I use special facebook page to contain all my content.

The other one is to use Facebook [Open Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/). For this approach each content item should have a separate page with facebook tags. To like is you should use POST request like this:

```
me/og.likes?object=http:\\url.to.your.content.item
```